# Добавить класс к родительскому div при определенном содержании одного из дочерних

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Имею построение таблицы из блоков. 
При определенном содержании одной из ячеек, нужно подсветить всю строку.
Строки иногда меняются местами. 
 Как это сделать на js или jQuery? Заранее спасибо

```html
<div class="stat-block-table__row">
    <span class="num">1</span>                  
    <span class="name">Вымпел</span>
    <span class="points">10</span>
</div>
<div class="stat-block-table__row">
    <span class="num">2</span>
    <span class="name">Зубило</span>                   
    <span class="points">9</span>
</div>
<div class="stat-block-table__row">
    <span class="num">3</span>
    <span class="name">Торпедо</span>                   
    <span class="points">4</span>
</div>
```

Допустим я хочу чтобы строка с "Зубило" была подсвечена при любом изменении порядка строк

```css
.highlight{
  background-color: #f28321;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

На JQuery:

```js
var search='Зубило'
$('.stat-block-table__row .name').filter((k,v)=>v.innerHTML==search).parent().addClass('highlight')
```

```css
.highlight{
  background-color: #f28321;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="stat-block-table__row">
    <span class="num">1</span>                  
    <span class="name">Вымпел</span>
    <span class="points">10</span>
</div>
<div class="stat-block-table__row">
    <span class="num">2</span>
    <span class="name">Зубило</span>                   
    <span class="points">9</span>
</div>
<div class="stat-block-table__row">
    <span class="num">3</span>
    <span class="name">Торпедо</span>                   
    <span class="points">4</span>
</div>
```